# How to get the proportion of elements that match between two vectors?

Tags: r, performance

I have two large vectors, for example:

```
set.seed(17)

vec1 <- paste0(sample(1:10, 10000000, replace = T), "_", sample(1:1000000000, 10000000))

vec2 <- paste0(sample(1:10, 1000000, replace = T), "_", sample(1:1000000000, 1000000))
```

And I need to identify the proportion of elements in vec2 that are also in vec1. I am currently using:

```
system.time({ 

prop <- table(vec2 %in% vec1)[[2]]/length(vec2) 

})
```

However, the actual vectors I am applying this to are VERY large (up to ~2,000,000,000 elements), so performance is very important. Is anyone able to suggest how  I can decrease the run-time?

Comment: Seems Slightly better with `intersect`, i.e. `length(intersect(vec2, vec1)) / length(vec2)`

Comment: Using `data.table`'s `%chin%` and `sum(vec2 %chin% vec1)/length(vec2)` seems a bit faster.

Comment: How many different values do you have in `vec2`?

Comment: No strings are repeated within the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some options with timings, also using @Sotos and @Henrik's suggestion from comments for comparison purposes.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

microbenchmark(a1 = table(vec2 %in% vec1)[[2]]/length(vec2) , 
               a2 = sum(vec2 %in% vec1)/length(vec2), 
               a3 = sum(!is.na(match(vec2, vec1)))/length(vec2), 
               a4 = length(intersect(vec2, vec1)) / length(vec2), 
               a5 = sum(vec2 %chin% vec1)/length(vec2))

#Unit: milliseconds
# expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#   a1 1269.84 1340.468 1667.251 1410.252 2191.750 2535.723   100
#   a2 1022.26 1086.938 1284.692 1124.565 1152.516 2286.028   100
#   a3 1023.59 1125.517 1387.592 1148.337 1852.645 3849.555   100
#   a4 1022.84 1088.056 1291.582 1122.846 1173.768 2277.901   100
#   a5  449.19  453.146  462.781  454.365  458.178  620.996   100
```

Clearly, Henrik's solution is the fastest.

**data**

```
set.seed(17)
vec1 <- paste0(sample(1:10, 10000000, replace = T), "_", 
               sample(1:1000000000, 10000000))
vec2 <- paste0(sample(1:10, 1000000, replace = T), "_", 
               sample(1:1000000000, 1000000))
```

Comment: `Rcpp` should be faster. I tried it but was complaining something with `Rtools` so I quit :)

Comment: you won't get duplicated elements with `intersect` so all results above might not be equal (but it seems there not supposed to be duplicates)